# "ZeroDivisionError: float division by zero" for image processing code using Rapberry Pi3 and camera

Tags: python, image-processing, camera, raspberry-pi3

I have edited these code, and these are the code:

```
from pyimagesearch.shapedetector import ShapeDetector
import argparse
import imutils
import cv2

ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-v", "--video",help="path to the (optional) video file")
ap.add_argument("-b", "--buffer",type=int, default=64,help="max buffer size")
args = vars(ap.parse_args())

if not args.get("video", False):
        camera = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
else:
        camera = v2.VideoCapture(args["video"])

while True:
        (grabbed, frame) = camera.read()
         if args.get("video") and not grabbed:
             break

         frame = imutils.rotate(frame, angle=180)
         resized = imutils.resize(frame, width=300)
         ratio = frame.shape[0] / float(resized.shape[0])

         gray = cv2.cvtColor(resized, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
         blurred = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (5, 5), 0)
         thresh = cv2.threshold(blurred, 60, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]

         cnts = cv2.findContours(thresh.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,
                            cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
         cnts = imutils.grab_contours(cnts)
         sd = ShapeDetector()


         for c in cnts:
             M = cv2.moments(c)
             cX = int((M["m10"] / M["m00"]) * ratio)
             cY = int((M["m01"] / M["m00"]) * ratio)
             shape = sd.detect(c)

             c = c.astype("float")
             c *= ratio
             c = c.astype("int")
             cv2.drawContours(frame, [c], -1, (0, 255, 0), 2)
             cv2.putText(frame, shape, (cX, cY), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX,
                    0.5, (255, 255, 255), 2)

             cv2.imshow("Gambar", frame)
             key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF

        # if the 'q' key is pressed, stop the loop
            if key == ord("q"):
                break
camera.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

After I ran it, I got notice that

File "detect_shapes_using_video.py", line 61, in

cX = int((M["m10"] / M["m00"]) * ratio)

ZeroDivisionError: float division by zero

What should I do? because I still beginner in python and I don't know how to do. These code are for image processing using camera in raspberry pi

Comment: If `M["m00"]` is zero, then you divide by zero. You can test for this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This block

```
M = cv2.moments(c)
cX = int((M["m10"] / M["m00"]) * ratio)
cY = int((M["m01"] / M["m00"]) * ratio)
```

is to find the centroid of the contour found in the image. `ZeroDivisionError: float division by zero` happened when `M["m00"] = 0` and it's because the contour is just a line.

You can add a condition like `if M["m00"] == 0: shape = "line"` to avoid this error.

[Edit] Here is my suggestion:

```
from pyimagesearch.shapedetector import ShapeDetector
import argparse
import imutils
import cv2

ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-v", "--video",help="path to the (optional) video file")
ap.add_argument("-b", "--buffer",type=int, default=64,help="max buffer size")
args = vars(ap.parse_args())

if not args.get("video", False):
    camera = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
else:
    camera = v2.VideoCapture(args["video"])

while True:
    (grabbed, frame) = camera.read()
     if args.get("video") and not grabbed:
         break

     frame = imutils.rotate(frame, angle=180)
     resized = imutils.resize(frame, width=300)
     ratio = frame.shape[0] / float(resized.shape[0])

     gray = cv2.cvtColor(resized, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
     blurred = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (5, 5), 0)
     thresh = cv2.threshold(blurred, 60, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]

     cnts = cv2.findContours(thresh.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,
                        cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
     cnts = imutils.grab_contours(cnts)
     sd = ShapeDetector()


     for c in cnts:
         M = cv2.moments(c)
         if(M["m00"]==0): # this is a line
             shape = "line" 
         else: 
             cX = int((M["m10"] / M["m00"]) * ratio)
             cY = int((M["m01"] / M["m00"]) * ratio)
             shape = sd.detect(c)

             c = c.astype("float")
             c *= ratio
             c = c.astype("int")
             cv2.drawContours(frame, [c], -1, (0, 255, 0), 2)
             cv2.putText(frame, shape, (cX, cY), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX,
                0.5, (255, 255, 255), 2)

             cv2.imshow("Gambar", frame)
             key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF

    # if the 'q' key is pressed, stop the loop
        if key == ord("q"):
            break
camera.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: I have do it, like this 'M = cv2.moments(c)
            cX = int((M["m10"] / M["m00"]) * ratio)
            cY = int((M["m01"] / M["m00"]) * ratio)
            shape = sd.detect(c)
            
 
            
            
            c = c.astype("float")
            c *= ratio
            c = c.astype("int")
            cv2.drawContours(frame, [c], -1, (0, 255, 0), 2)
            cv2.putText(frame, shape, (cX, cY), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX,
                        0.5, (255, 255, 255), 2)
            if M["m00"]==0:
                    shape = "line" ' but stil not working

Comment: May be I have mistake to use it or something?? @Ha Bom

Comment: @Alfarabialhaqi, you're welcome, don't forget to accept my answer.